# Engine speed, vibration and rpm

Tags: motorcycle, vibration, rpm, speedometer, apache-rtr

I have few doubts with my motorcycle (Apache RTR 180 ABS version).

1. When I ride on top gear I have noticed the engine vibration is reduced much when at 84-86 Km speed (RPM around 6400). I feel vibration below and above that speed (or RPM). If I ride in this less vibration speed (which I feel) will this be good for engine? And if the vibration is less does that mean the fuel consumption is also less? Is there any way that I can lock my motorcycle at this top speed?
2. Occasionally  I compare RPM meter with the speedometer. When my motorcycle was new it was running at 60 Km at 5000 RPM, later it increased to 65 Km for same RPM. Initially I thought it is tuned while running on the road. From few days I noticed it is showing 65 to 68 Km for the same RPM. Is this common for engines?